# Test Async $http real calls for angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http, karma-mocha

I want to do an e2e test of a angularjs service, without mocking the $http call. The call to fsSvc.getSubject results in multiple embedded async calls, eventually ending in calling the callback function where I have put the call to done.

Not sure this doesn't work - shouldn't $http make the call for real if its not mocked?:

```
 it('should pass auth', function(done) {
        inject(function (fsSvc) {
            var cb = sinon.spy();
            stubs.updateRecord = sinon.stub(dataSvc, 'updateRecord');

            dataSvc.LO.famSrch.access_token_expires = false;

            fsSvc.getSubject("abc", function(err, data) {
                console.log("err:" + err);
                done();
                cb();
            });

            $timeout.flush();
            expect(dataSvc.LO.famSrch.discovery).to.not.be.undefined;
            expect(dataSvc.LO.famSrch.discovery.links).to.not.be.undefined;
            expect(dataSvc.LO.famSrch.access_token).to.not.be.undefined;
            expect(dataSvc.LO.famSrch.username).to.equal("test");
            expect(dataSvc.LO.famSrch.password).to.equal(btoa("test"));
            expect(dataSvc.LO.famSrch.access_token_expires).to.be.greaterThan(3600000);

            expect(stubs.updateRecord.callCount).to.equal(1);
            expect(stubs.updateRecord.args[0][1]).to.equal("localOption");
            expect(cb.callCount).to.equal(1);
        })
    });
```

Comment: Are you by chance including `angular-mocks.js` in your page? If so, you'll be getting the mocked version of `$httpBackend`. Also, e2e tests in Angular are typically run via protractor and you manipulate the `browser` object. What you've got in your question looks like a unit test

Comment: It is technically a unit test, but thats what I want.  I don't want to have to start up protractor and execute a service by calling some web page DOM element.  I just want to test the service.   angular-mocks IS configured in karma, I should have thought of that.  Maybe I'll try an alternate karma configuration

Comment: ugh, then I lose inject...

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend, it introduces the `passThrough` method

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but then you have to jump thru hoops to only include when testing.  Be nice if you could "add" the dependency in angular.mock.module

Comment: @ed4becky Not sure what you mean by jumping through hoops. Don't you just enable pass through in your unit tests? Your production code doesn't have to change.

Comment: you have to include mocke2e module as a dependency when defining your app module

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with including e2e. Why is that an issue for you?

If you do decide to give ngMockE2E a try than keep in mind that it does not handle async / promise responses.

For example, if your mock response is a promise it won't work. Instances like going to the DB or using something like WebSQL / IndexedDB ( or other in memory DB ) won't work.

I have developed an angular plugin called [angular-mocks-async](https://github.com/amoldavsky/angular-mocks-async) to work it out. Here is an example of a mock:

```
var app = ng.module( 'mockApp', [
    'ngMockE2E',
    'ngMockE2EAsync'
]);

app.run( [ '$httpBackend', '$q', function( $httpBackend, $q ) {

    $httpBackend.whenAsync(
        'GET',
        new RegExp( 'http://api.example.com/user/.+$' )
    ).respond( function( method, url, data, config ) {

        var re = /.*\/user\/(\w+)/;
        var userId = parseInt(url.replace(re, '$1'), 10);

        var response = $q.defer();

        setTimeout( function() {

            var data = {
                userId: userId
            };
            response.resolve( [ 200, "mock response", data ] );

        }, 1000 );

        return response.promise;

    });

}]);
```